# How to remove a "commit branch" in bazaar?

Tags: bazaar

I have a trunk branch "A", and a testing branch "B".
"B" is branched from "A".

Now I want to merge "B" into "A", and did a "bzr merge -pull ${HOME}/B" under "A".
Then I realize that if now I do a "bzr info" under "A", I will find a new "submit branch B".
This sounds bad to me because all the committed changes in "A" will go to "B".

So my question is:
1. Is "bzr merge -pull ${HOME}/B" under "A" a good way to do what I want?
2. How to remove the "submit branch B" under "A"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The submit branch is primarily used as a default for `bzr send` and `bzr bundle`. This should not create any problems for you (if you do use these commands, you can override the submit branch on the command line). It is also the default location for future merges if for some reason you do not specify one. The "submit" in "submit branch" refers to submitting changes for review, not to commits.

Most other commands should not be affected. Commits will go to the original branch unless you've made it a bound branch via `bzr bind` or `bzr checkout`, and those will go to the bound location, not the submit branch; pushes will go to the default push location, which is also different.

You can use `bzr merge --no-remember` to not set the submit branch (or edit `.bzr/branch/branch.conf` to remove the path afterwards). Similarly, you can use `--remember` to override an existing submit branch location.